Transforming sentences with perfect infintive
I want to transform the following sentences into the past.

I would prefer to go there
A. I would prefer to have gone there
B. I would have preferred to go there
C. I would have preferred to have gone there


To me all have the same meaning and are correct. A is like saying from a present perspective I wanted to do in the past. B is like saying from a past perspective what I wanted to do in what was the future then. C is like saying what I wanted to do in the past even before. Am I correct? One more question. Does it work the same way with just "prefer"?

I prefer to ride a bike to school
A. I prefer to have ridden a bike to school
B. I preferred to ride a bike to school
C. I preferred to have ridden a bike to school



No, they don't 'all have the same meaning'. 1B is the natural version; at the time when you had the option of going 'there', you wanted to do so (with the implication that you didn't, but had to stay at home or go somewhere else).
1A says (rather oddly) that now you would rather be in the situation of having gone there in the past. It would be much more natural to say "I wish I had gone there."
1C just sounds odd with the two perfect tenses.
The same applies to the second group of sentences - A odd, B natural, C very odd - except that B implies that you did cycle to school.

I could say, at the foot of the gallows, 'I would prefer not to have been sentenced to death', but I suspect that my lifelong aversion to stating the obvious would still be active.

Re C: "My buddies twisted my arm to skip the museum visit on the school trip, but I would have preferred to have gone there" - sounds OK to me? (BrE) - and better than B.

@abligh - Well, I would say I would have preferred to go, as the second perfect tense isn't really necessary, but it might be idiomatic for some people.

@KateBunting Even if the school trip is a long past event? I agree if the school trip is upcoming but the arm twisting has already happened (sorry I should have made my example clearer)

@abligh - Would have preferred  already places the incident in the past. To me, using a second perfect tense places 'going' even further back.

@Kate 1C sounded fine to me on first glance (native speaker, Maritimes), but the more I think about it, the less literal sense it makes, for the same reason you said.

Regarding the first part of your question, I think your readings of all three sentences seem correct and idiomatic. They strike me as a bit casual, but otherwise natural. Maybe 1a is the hardest to find a context for; but I think it would be plausible to say "I'm looking for work now, and regret having gone to the cheaper school instead of the more prestigious school, so now I wish I had gone there."
I don't think there's a strong difference in meaning between 1b and 1c. The second clause may be in the past tense just because it sounds better.
Suppose that time 1 is last week, time 2 is yesterday, and time 3 is right now.
I believe you are saying that sentence 1b ("I would have preferred to go there") means it is now time 3, and at time 2, I wanted to go there at time 2. And you're saying that sentence 1c ("I would have preferred to have gone there") means it is now time 3, and at time 2, I wish I had gone there at time 1.
This distinction is possible, but in practice I would not put too much weight on it--it seems unlikely that the speaker is making a conscious distinction here. If someone said "I would have preferred to have gone to Harvard," I would interpret that as describing their past preferences about what they were doing at the time. Like, they've graduated now, but when they were in Uni, they wished they could transfer. But that's also how I would interpret "I would have preferred to go to Harvard," unless there's some stronger context to make the distinction between those two statements.
--
Regarding your second example, 2A and 2C seem unnatural: it feels like the speaker is stressing that there's something they like about the feeling of having ridden a bike. (Maybe they get a "runner's high" or feel relaxed after exercise or something?) I don't think these work the same way as example 1.
